# Struct getter and Setter using inline assembly in solidity

Tags: solidity, assembly

I have a storage slot defined

```
bytes32 internal constant USER_STRUCT_SLOT =
        0xd722976edd762e336e189ef10d2d356b8698dc8a2e03a97b539ab9d3974a1630;

struct UserData {
        uint256 level;
        uint256 stakeToken;
        uint256 stableToken;
        uint256 rewards;
        uint256 rewardPercentTimes100;
        uint256 lastUpdateTime;
}
```

We have written a getter for this like :

```
function getUserDataStructValue(MyStruct memory data) private view returns (uint256 _u, uint256 _v, uint256 _w, uint256 _x, uint256 _y, uint256 _z) {
    assembly {
        _u := mload(data)
        _v := mload(add(data,0x20))
        _w := mload(add(data,0x40))
        _x := mload(add(data,0x60))
        _y := mload(add(data,0x80))
        _z := mload(add(data,0xA0))
    }
}
```

Not sure about how the Retrieval and setting of the Structure will work wrt the slot we provided

**How to set the Values in a struct using inline assembly code ?**

Comment: You use `mstore`. For example,  `mstore(add(data, 0x20), _u)`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more with an example? It would be very helpful